# Odoo 10, Create draft invoice in website_sale after confirme sale

Tags: odoo-10

I want to generate a draft invoice in odoo website_sale after the confirmation of sale, so I inherit the controller, and here is the code

```
@http.route(['/shop/confirmation'], type='http', auth="public", website=True)
def payment_confirmation(self, **post):
    sale_order_id = http.request.session.get('sale_last_order_id')
    if sale_order_id:
        order = http.request.env['sale.order'].sudo().browse(sale_order_id)
        # here I want to create a draft invoice
        return http.request.render("website_sale.confirmation", {'order': order})
    else:
        return http.request.redirect('/shop')
```

The question is : How can I create an invoice draft from the order ?

Answer (score 0):

after two days I found the solution, here is my solution

```
    @http.route(['/shop/confirmation'], type='http', auth="public", website=True)
def payment_confirmation(self, **post):
    sale_order_id = http.request.session.get('sale_last_order_id')
    if sale_order_id:
        order = http.request.env['sale.order'].sudo().browse(sale_order_id)
        for line in order.order_line:
            line.qty_to_invoice = line.product_uom_qty
        order.action_invoice_create()
        return http.request.render("website_sale.confirmation", {'order': order})
    else:
        return http.request.redirect('/shop')
```